# Не могу #include <variant>. C++

Tags: c++

Хочу подключить библиотеку `variant` (Которая на некоторых сайтах указывается как стандартная и есть на С++17), но мне выдает ошибку `No such file or directory` 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Code::blocks скачан отсюда http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26 (codeblocks-17.12mingw-setup.exe) , больше я вроде бы с ним никак не манипулировал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так а опцию вы включили? Может лучше руками `std=c++17` вписать?

Comment: Codeblocks известен тем, что с ним в комплекте идет какой-то древний GCC (5.x вроде). Поставьте последний MinGW-w64.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант (хе-хе) использовать `std::experimental::variant`, если не удаётся включить c++17.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос через [edit] информацию о версии IDE, откуда качали и т.д., чтобы иметь возможность повторить ваши шаги и реализовать [mcve].

Comment: @AnT В code::blocks я как нуб в воде( в смысле не рыба), можно ли ссылку где обьясняется как включать опции? Или более развернутое обьяснение, чтобы я мог по другому загуглить (просто мне что-то не то выдает)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0 а такая версия?

Comment: [Тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler%20support) написано, что нужен как минимум GCC 7. Качать отсюда: http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds